# Changing Webform's submit button's text

Tags: webforms

The famous [Webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) module gives a beautiful nicely designed "Submit" button.

How can I change its text from "Submit", to anything else? I want to change it to another language but I found no way to do it by the UI, or by the Translation mechanism.

Comment: Do you have your site with multi-language?

Answer (score 5):

Well, normally the webform provides you the facility to edit the submit button form text at

Go to webform->form settings->Submit button text

Or either way you can use the string override [module](https://www.drupal.org/project/stringoverrides)

Hope it may help you!

Answer (score 4):

You can change the submit button text of a webform very easily. Follow these steps :

1. Edit specific webform of which you want to change the submit text.
2. Go to `Webform -> Form` Settings.
3. Go to `Advanced Settings -> Submit Button Label` field.
4. Here you can add the desired text you want to appear on the submit button.